# Codeigniter Model autoloading not working for MY_Loader class

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, autoloader

I've added "header_model" into codeigniter's autoload.php file. now its:

```
$autoload['model'] = array("header_model");
```

And i also can successfully use `$this->header_model` in other controllers.

But can't use it in `MY_Loader` class, which is extension of `CI_Loader`.

Example:
Pages controller  *located at application/controllers/*:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
      var_dump($this->header_model->get_menus()); //echoes data from database.
    }

}
```

MY_Loader class *(located at application/core/ folder)*:

```
<?php
   class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

   function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();
   }

   public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
   {

       $menuArray = $this->header_model->get_menus(); //echoes errors
       //like: Undefined property: MY_Loader::$header_model
       $vars["menuArray"] = $menuArray;
   }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$this` is two different objects in `Pages` and `MY_Loader`.

Autoloaded classes, including models, wind up being variables in the controller. So `$this->->header_model...` works within `Pages` because it is a controller. But the object `$this` inside the function `template` is the instance of the `MY_Loader` class. And that class has no variable called `header_model`.

In order to reference the controller use `get_instance()`. Here's how

```
public function template($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $menuArray = $CI->header_model->get_menus(); //echoes errors
    //like: Undefined property: MY_Loader::$header_model
    $vars["menuArray"] = $menuArray;
}
```

Not part of your problem but I'd like to point out that you do not need the `__construct()` function in `MY_Model`. If a child class does not do any initialization in a constructor there is no need to create a constructor only to call `parent::__construct();`. PHP will find the parent class constructor execute it automatically.